# If the quadratic equation $x^2+(2-\tan\theta)x-(1+\tan\theta)=0$ has two integral roots,

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

If the quadratic equation $x^2+(2-\tan\theta)x-(1+\tan\theta)=0$ has two integral roots,then find the sum of all possible values of $\theta$ in interval $(0,2\pi).$

---

The given quadratic equation is $x^2+(2-\tan\theta)x-(1+\tan\theta)=0$.
So $x=\frac{\tan\theta-2\pm\sqrt{\tan^2\theta+8}}{2}$
I am stuck here.I do not know what is the condition for two integer roots.

Comment: May be if $x \in \mathbb Z$, then $\tan^2 \theta +8 -$ perfect square.?

Comment: $a^2-b^2=8$,how many possible $(a,b)$? find this and you will get answer.

Comment: Note that $\tan\theta$ must also be an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=\tan \theta$. We need that $t^2+8$ be a perfect square, so $$t^2+8=s^2\qquad(*)$$

When $\theta\in (0,2\pi)$, the value $t$ can be all real but if $t$ and $s$ must be integers we have $s=t+h$ where $h$ is a positive integer. It follows $$2ht+h^2=8\qquad (**)$$ An obvious solution of $(*)$ is $t=1$ so for $(**)$ we have to solve $$2h+h^2=8$$ whose only solution is $h=2$ but for $t>1$ there are no solutions for $(**)$

So the only values to be considered are $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ which correspond to $t=\tan \theta=1$

Comment: The answer given in the book is that sum of the roots is $4\pi$,i think $t=-1$ is also the solution which gives $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}$

Comment: I have seen $t=-1$ but this correspond to the angle $\frac{-\pi}{4}$ which is not in $(0, 2\pi)$ so I have discarded this negative value. Was I wrong? But the other values you give here I think are truly valid.

Answer (score 0):

As roots are integers tan has to be an integer .  so $$\tan(x)=\sqrt{n^2-8}$$ thus $3,-3$(keeping in mind the graph of $n^2$ i have concluded it.) are only two integers who give a perfect squares thus now $x=\pi/4$ now again tan is positive in third quadrant so $x=5\pi/4$ thus sum of all such theta is $3\pi/2$